# How to remove NULL from array in Athena

Tags: sql, arrays, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have arrays aggregated with this query:

```
select field_name1, 
       field_name2, 
       "array_agg"(DISTINCT <field_name3>) "array_agg"
from <table_name>
group by <field_name1>
```

Problem is that some outputs have NULL values in them.

```
['element1', 'element2', NULL]
```

How can we remove the NULL from array when aggregate values.

I have tried

```
select field_name1, 
       field_name2, 
       "array_remove"("array_agg"(DISTINCT <field_name1>), NULL) "array_agg_drop_NULL""array_agg"
from <table_name>
group by <field_name1>
```

but it returns output with all blanks.

Comment: looks like sql, so do a where field is not null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#filter) function:

```sql
select filter(array['element1', 'element2', NULL], el -> el is not null) filtered
```

Output:

| filtered |
| --- |
| [element1, element2] |